# UILabels Right-filled with Dots

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have, in a collection view, a list of about 10 rows in a grid format that I want to look sort of like the following:

```
SomeText.................     17
SomeMoreText.............     22
EvenMoreText.............    204
Another Row..............     11
Etc......................      6
```

My objective is to have whatever text I place in the first column padded on the right with a sufficient number of dots to fill out the field.  However, the rows of dots must be aligned which I assume means the use of a fixed pitch.

I can think of various brute force ways to do this.  My questions are:

a) Is there any built-in functionality I'm missing that may make this cleaner?
b) Is there a way to accomplish this (particularly, the alignment) without a fixed-pitch font?

TIA for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a standard label size and compare your text to the size to fill it with dots.

```
CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake([Your standard label width], height);

CGSize textSize = [[label text] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[label font]}];
for (;textSize.width < labelSize.width;) {
    label.text = [label.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the way to do it with content hugging/compression resistance.
Here is the interface builder solution:
[image: UILabel filled with dots]